# Multidimensional array php post

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I created a form to input a schedule to a certain location and the location will have multiple schedule
The form looks like this (I can add more input form as much as I need)

```
<input name="location[]" type="text">
<input name="address[]" type="text">
    <input name="day[]" type="text">
    <input name="start[]" type="text">
    <input name="end[]" type="text">
```

And so on. The problem is, I want to insert the `location` and `address` to `addresses` table, and `day`,`start`,`end` to `schedules` table and make sure that the `schedule` has the right `address_id` just like below

`addresses` table

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | location |  address |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | loc 1    |  addr 1  |
| 2  | loc 2    |  addr 2  |
+----+----------+----------+
```

`schedules` table

```
 +----+----------+----------+-------+------------+
 | id |    day   |   start  |  end  | address_id |
 +----+----------+----------+-------+------------+
 | 1  | day a    |  start a | end a |      1     |
 | 2  | day b    |  start b | end b |      1     |
 | 3  | day c    |  start c | end c |      2     |
 | 4  | day d    |  start d | end d |      2     |
 +----+----------+----------+-------+------------+
```

I've read that I need to use `foreach` to do this, but the problem is how to loop the input and make sure that the schedule has the right `address_id` value?

I use laravel:

```
$address = Input::get('address');
$location = Input::get('location');
$day = Input::get('day');
$start = Input::get('start');
$end = Input::get('end');

foreach($location as $key => $value) {
    $addr = new Address;
    $addr->location = $location[$key];
    $addr->address = $address[$key];
    $addr->save();
    foreach($day as $key => $value) {
        $sched = new Schedule;
        $sched->day = $day[$key];
        $sched->start = $start[$key];
        $sched->end = $end[$key];
        $sched->address_id = $addr->id;
        $sched->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: So which of the PHP MYSQL API's are you using? `mysqli_*` or `PDO`?

Comment: It would also be useful to see what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop by `address` for example and insert first of all in `address` table. After that you need to get the id of the inserted row and use it when you insert in `schedules` table.

As you didn't try any code I just explain here how you should do and if something is not working let me know what have you tried and what error you have.

```
foreach($_POST['address'] as $key => $value){
   //insert to address table: $_POST['location'][$key] and $_POST['address'][$key]
   //$last_inserted_id_from_address = Get the latest inserted id from address table.
   //insert to schedules tables: $_POST['day'][$key] ,.... and $last_inserted_id_from_address
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You don't need to loop twice if you want to have match 1 to 1.
Change your loop to this:

```
foreach($location as $key => $value) {
    $addr = new Address;
    $addr->location = $location[$key];
    $addr->address = $address[$key];
    $addr->save();

    //Use the same $key when creating Schedule. For each address will create one schedule.
    $sched = new Schedule;
    $sched->day = $day[$key];
    $sched->start = $start[$key];
    $sched->end = $end[$key];
    $sched->address_id = $addr->id;
    $sched->save();

}
```

Comment: I have tried, and from your code, the `day`, `start`, `end` values will end up repeated 2 times, `address_id` 1 and 2 will both have the `day a`, `day b`, `day c`, and `day d` value, while I want to make the `day a` and `day b` only connected to `address_id` 1; `day c` and `day d` only connected to `address_id` 2